# MySQL query to get value of coumn 1 having set of values in column 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with data like:

```
==============
 item | tagid
--------------
 1111 |   101
 1111 |   102
 2222 |   101
 2222 |   103
 3333 |   104
 4444 |   105
 4444 |   106
 5555 |   101
 5555 |   103
==============
```

I want all items with tagids `101` and `103`. In the sample above, that would be items `2222` and `5555`, since both of them have tags `101` and `103`.

How can I do this?

Comment: will there be always 2 records you want in common, or do you want it to work for records matching more then 2 times.

Comment: @GauravLad there will be more sometimes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tagid is unique for each item (ie the combination of item and tagid is unqiue):

```
select item
from mytable
where tagid in (101, 103)
group by item
having count(*) = 2
```

or if not unique (unlikely), use `having count(distinct tagid) = 2`

Comment: could you tell me the difference between `having count(distinct tagid) = 2` and `having count(*) = 2` ?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ: first counts all rows in the group while second counts only uniq `tagid`s in the group.

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ `count(*)` does less work, so it will probably execute slightly faster. The behavioural difference is that `count(*)` counts the total number of rows even if there are duplicate tagids for the same item.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select item from table
where tagid in(101, 103)
group by item
having count(distinct tagid) = 2
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, DISTINCT *should* be redundant in this particular example.

Comment: @Strawberry, no you are wrong. Then it will select item with `101, 101`. depends on data, but I would prefer to be guaranted

Comment: The 'R' in RDBMS inplies that data has a relationship with other data. For that to be put in to effect, it's necessary to provide a PRIMARY KEY. So, given that the OP only has two columns, if those are not then components of a compound PRIMARY KEY, then the OP potentially has bigger problems with their data. Which is why I say '*should*'

Comment: @Strawberry, you are absolutely correct. Sorry, my english just need to be improved a little.

Comment: I assure you, it's considerably better than my Georgian

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
select item
from tbl
where tagid in (101, 103)
group by item
having count(distinct tagid) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item
FROM tbl
WHERE tagid in (101, 103)
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tagid) = 2;
```

Answer (score -3):

Its not clear. You already have items 2222 and 5555 with requested tags.

```
2222 101
5555 103
```

But also you have other tags for the items:

```
2222 102
5555 101
```

you need remove last data

```
delete from TABLE where item='2222' and tagid='102'
delete from TABLE where item='5555' and tagid='101'
```

Comment: There is a solution for this problem. Not requiring people to remove a data manually.

Comment: The fact that OP already has the data present in the table is not the same as having a query return this data specifically.